# Evaluate indefinite integral numerically in matlab/mathematica that it cannot do symbolically

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to calculate the integral of a function in Matlab and Mathematica that the software cannot do symbolically.

Here is my MatLab code so far, but I understand it may not be very helpful as is.

```
f = @(t) asin(0.5*sin(t));
a = @(t) sin(t);
F = int(f,t)   % Matlab can't do this
F = 
int(asin(sin(t)/2), t)
A = int(a,t)   % This works
A =
-cos(t)

dt = 1/(N-1); % some small number
for i=1:N
    F(i) = integral(f,(i-1)*dt,i*dt);
    A(i) = integral(a,(i-1)*dt,i*dt);
end
```

Both of the calculations in  the for loop give a rough approximation of `f` or `a` not their integrals after multiplying by `dt`.

On the math stack-exchange I found a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789176/approximation-of-an-indefinite-integral) that derives a finite difference like method for the integral at a point. However, when I did the calculation in Matlab it output a scaled down version of `f` which was evident after plotting (see above for what I mean by scaled down). I think that's because for smaller intervals the integral basically approximates the function to varying degrees of accuracy (again see above).

I am trying to get either a symbolic equation for the integral, or an approximation of the integral of the function at each location.

So my question is then **if I have a function f that MatLab and Mathematica cannot easily take the integral of**

1. **can I approximate the integral directly with an integral calculator besides the default ones?** (`int`,`integral`,`trapz`)

or

2. **can I approximate the function with finite differences first and then evaluate the integral symbolically?**

Comment: What do you mean "besides the default ones" - what are you classing as the default solvers and why do you think they won't work? The simplest numerical integrator is `trapz` in Matlab, why wouldn't this work? What is your expected output if your limits are indefinite (you cannot evaluate anything numerically in this case)?

Comment: I explained why they don't work, the integration interval is too small to output anything but the function you input into the calculator.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. We cannot run your current code to produce whatever non-result you're getting, and you've not suggested what the expected output might be. Can you give an example where the integrand can be algebraically integrated, so we can verify any results?

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't run the code as provided, it's not difficult. But I made edits that should make it easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is nearly fine it's just that

```
for i=1:N
    F(i) = integral(f,0,i*dt);
end
```

You could also do

```
F(1)=integral(f,0,dt)
for i=2:N
    F(i) = F(i-1)+integral(f,(i-1)*dt,i*dt);
end
```

Second option is surely more efficient

Because the primitive is really F(x)=int(f(x), 0, x) (0 defines a certain constant ) and for sufficiently small dx you have shown that f(x)=int(f(x), x,x+dx)/dx i. You have proven that MATLAB intégral function does its job.

For example let's take [image]= [image] the function above will compute [image] if you wish to compute [image] just replace 0 above by the constant `a` you like.

now [image] and so you should get `F` containing a discretization of [image]

Comment: I know `int` "does it's job". Maybe my method is faulty but if I integrate f(x) the integral should act like a transformation. The function is not exponential so f(x) is not equal `int(f,x)`.

Comment: Have you tried thé fix i have you (replacing (i-1)dt by 0) ? I am merely saying that   f(x)=int(f(x), x,x+dx)/dx when dx goes to zéro which is what you observe without the fix.

Comment: No I haven't but the reason is because I want to move the intervals of my integral. Starting from `0:dt`, up to `T-dt:T`. Make sense?

Comment: I'll try this later, thanks. I won't be able to for awhile.

Comment: Definitely, it'll just be awhile till I have access to Matlab

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding sooner, but this method does not work. For instance let `f = @(t) sin(2*pi*t);` the integral is `F = @(t) -cos(2*pi*t)/(2*pi);`. I tried both of the versions of the for loops you provided, but they are both offset by a constant value 1/(2*pi);

Comment: Your answer is still not clear, and outputs an incorrect result.

I just copy and pasted all of your code and got the same result, offset by 1/(2*pi). Here is a link to the graph I am getting, hopefully this helps diagnose the problem. https://photos.app.goo.gl/rCmsnv2cGtJZz99g6 

I will also open a chat.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer in the end I'll be deleting my comments tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180292/discussion-between-wngatrc456-and-npe).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in general is by far the best method I would say but if certain restrictions on your functions are allowable then there is a second method.

For two functions `f` and `g` see below

```
T = 1;  % Period
NT = 1;  % Number of periods
dt = 0.01; % time interval
time = 0:dt:NT*T;  % time

syms t
x = K*sin(2*pi*t+B);   % edit as appropriate

% f = A/tanh(K)*tanh(K*sin(2*pi*t+p))
% g = A/asin(K)*asin(K*sin(2*pi*t+p))
```

formulas found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series)

```
f = A1/tanh(K1)*(2^(2*1)-1)*2^(2*1)*bernoulli(2*1)/factorial(2*1)*x^(2*1-1);
% |K1|<pi/2
g = A2/asin(K2)*factorial(2*0)/(2^(2*0)*factorial(0)^2*(2*0+1))*x^(2*0+1);
% |K2|<1
```

there are no such limitations in the accepted answer

```
N = 60;
for k=2:N
    a1 = (2^(2*k)-1)*2^(2*k)*bernoulli(2*k)/factorial(2*k);
    f = f + A1/tanh(K1)*a1*x^(2*k-1);

    a2 = factorial(2*k)/(2^(2*k)*factorial(k)^2*(2*k+1));
    g = g + A2/asin(K2)*a*x^(2*k+1);
end
```

MATLAB can calculate `sin^n(t)` for n being an integer.

```
F = int(f,t);
phi = double(subs(F,t,time));

G = int(g,t);
psi = double(subs(G,t,time));
```